Inverse Filtering
I am having trouble with some signal processing and are wondering if there might be someone who might like to help.
This is how I see the problem:
An input communication signal is transmitted through a channel that is dominated by an unknown low-pass filter which distorts the signal so badly that it cannot be reliably decoded. The first part of the signal is a known synchronisation pattern which we can identify despite the distortion.
Since we know the synchronisation pattern and have measured the filtered version of it,  we can estimate the transfer function of the unknown low-pass filter as a Laplace polynomial of the form TF(s) = (b0s^n+b1s^(n-1)+...+bn)/(a0s^m+a1s^(m-1)+...+am). Through repeated simulation and comparison to the measured signal, we can find a transfer function that "reasonably" approximates the actual low-pass filter of the system.
Armed with the "reasonable" approximation of the system transfer function in the form TF(s) = (b0s^n+b1s^(n-1)+...+bn)/(a0s^m+a1s^(m-1)+...+am), we can then find the inverse as TF_Inv(s) = (a0s^m+a1s^(m-1)+...+am)/(b0s^n+b1s^(n-1)+...+bn). Application of this inverse to the measured data should recover the original signal or at least a reasonable approximation thereof. For simple canned examples this works but there are inherent stability problems in the inverse transfer function.
How should the inverse transfer functions be adjusted in light of the Routh_Horwitz Stablility Criterion so that an estimate of the input signal is recovered without oscillation?
I am using python's scipy.signal library.
